# Oracle Apex display message when row not inserted in DML process

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a requirement where in DML process, I need to write code such that if the user_requirement  exists for user, the message should display on application.

Requirement already exists.

Else it should insert into table.

How can i display the message?

```
Declare
count_v number;
begin
select count(1) into count_v  from user_requirement where user = :APP_USER;
If count_v=0,
then insert into user_requirement values(:APP_USER,:P1_rEQ);
else
**DISPLAY MESSAGE HERE**
END;
```

Apex 20.2

Comment: what happens *after* the message ? Is it just a message on the screen - like an alert region ? Does the user have to confirm ? It would help to describe the business flow in more detail.

Comment: Just message on screen

Answer (score 1):

Modify code to

```
DECLARE
   count_v  NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (1)
     INTO count_v
     FROM user_requirement
    WHERE USER = :app_user;

   IF count_v = 0
   THEN
      INSERT INTO user_requirement
           VALUES ( :app_user, :p1_req);
   ELSE
      raise_application_error (-20000, NULL);          --> this
   END IF;
END;
```

and add **Error message** e.g.

> Requirement already exists.

Comment: This will work but the end user will get an error page with this message - that might not be what they want.

Comment: Error page? When I tried it (on 18.2), I got a small yellow-ish rectangle in the upper-right corner, @Koen.

Comment: Hmmm - I thought the raise_application_error would redirect to the dreaded error page but didn't check. Apologies.

Comment: No problem, @Koen :) It is considered to be an "unhandled exception" and Apex displays message written in "Error message" property.

Comment: Or just let constraint on table raise the exception, to be caught by application error handler? No need for manual code.

Comment: Right, but that would return ugly ORA-00001 which isn't *user friendly*, @Scott. Wouldn't it?

Comment: If you read through the example handler in the documentation, you'll see how it turns these messages into a user-friendly format.

Comment: I'm on 18.2, @Scott, and - if I remember well - exceptions raised by e.g. triggers do look like "ORA-20000: some text here". We plan to upgrade in a week or two, though. Is that user-friendly format related to more recent version(s) then ours?

Comment: Exceptions raised via a trigger would need to be specifically targeted, but can be done in the same handler.  But the business rule in the OP can be defined with a unique index.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I'm not commenting the original question any more, @Scott; "trigger that raises an exception" was just my remark.